# Attribute value "undefined" in model when used inside aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, modal

i am getting undefined when i try to pass attribute value (from button which opens a modal) to Java script function.

Component:

```
<aura:component>
.....
 <button type="button" data-id="test" onclick="{!c.DetailPage}" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click</button>
....

</aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
 DetailPage : function(component, event, helper) {
// tried multilple scenarios..all returning "undefined"
        alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
        alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
        alert($(this).data('id'));
        alert($(this).data("id"));
        alert($(this).data().id);
    },
```

After retrieving this value i need to set this value to my drop down list..

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>

<button type="button" data-id="{!v.options}"    ...../>
..
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="ProductPlatform" class="form-control" label="Product Platform" change="{!c.onSelectChange}" required="true"> 
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.pltfrmGrpOptions}" var="level" indexVar="index">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!index ==0}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption value="true" label="{!level}" text="{!level}"/>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
        <ui:inputSelectOption label="{!level}" text="{!level}" />
        </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get current button attributes from event object using following way

```
event.target.getAttribute("data-id")
```

Comment: Question Edited. This helps. But i need to set this data-id value to my drop down list. on the first attempts alert(event.target.getAttribute("data-id")) returns null, on second it gives correct value.

Comment: i can use `component.set()` to set the value ...Coming to `(event.target.getAttribute("data-id")` but it returns null on first click.. Second click it gives value... but do not set the Drop down.